# Async with redux works? But still gives error, should I ignore it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using a mix of laravel, react.

Attempting to implement the redux-thunk middleware. 
I am having issues with async calls.
I would like to use jquery for ajax (which successfully retrieve the API data, but I am getting an error which reads,

"Error: dispatch is not a function", meaning I cannot make any changes to the store. From what I understand dispatch and GetState is passed through the thunk middle-ware. Correct?So why am I not able to use the function?

It also gives me an error which reads: "Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?"

Another issue that arises, after trying to deal with the above issue is: "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

I have read many similar questions but I still cannot seem to get it to work.

"Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

#### index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import FilterBar from './SideBar/FilterBar';
import Store from '../redux/store/mainStore';
import { REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE_FILTER,ADD_ATTRIBUTE_TO_FILTER, removeAttribute } from '../redux/actions/actions';

Store.subscribe(()=>{
    console.log("store changes", Store.getState())
})



console.log(Store.getState());

Store.dispatch({
type:ADD_ATTRIBUTE_TO_FILTER,
payload:{'make':23}

})


if (document.getElementById('InventoryDisplay')) {
  
        
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={Store}>
        <FilterBar/>
        </Provider>
        ,document.getElementById('FilterBar'));

   
}
```

#### mainstore.js

```

```js
import { createStore,applyMiddleware,combineReducers,compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {inventoryFilter,availableAttributes} from '../reducers/reducer';


const Store = createStore(

///combine imported reducers
    combineReducers({
    activeFilter:inventoryFilter,
    availableAttributes:availableAttributes

},
///initilize store
{},


applyMiddleware(thunk)


));



export default Store;
```

```

#### actions.js what is relevant

```

```js
///first case
const getAttributes2 = (dispatch) => {
  return(
    $.ajax('/getFilteredAttributes/', {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(response => {
        dispatch(addAttribute("make",32));
    }).fail((xhr, status, error) => {
        console.log("failed");
    })
  )

};

///second case
const getAttributes = (dispatch) => {
  return ()=>{}

}


export {
  ADD_ATTRIBUTE_TO_FILTER,addAttribute,
  REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE_FILTER,removeAttribute,
  GET_INVENTORY,getInventory,
  GET_AVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTES,getAttributes,
  

}
```

```

#### component connect to store that dispatch action

```

```js
import React from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as ActionCreators from '../../../redux/actions/actions';

class DropDownList extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.addAttributes("make",32)
        this.props.getAttributes()
        this.props.removeAttributes("make",32)
            

    }
    render(){
  
        return(
        
            <div>
            </div>

        )




        
    }






    
}





function mapStatesToProps(state){
   return{
    activeFilters:state.activeFilter,
    availableAttributes:state.availableAttributes
   } 
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addAttributes: (type,value) => {
            dispatch(ActionCreators.addAttribute(type,value))
          },
        removeAttributes: (type,value) => {
            dispatch(ActionCreators.removeAttribute(type,value))
          },
        getAttributes: () => {
            dispatch(ActionCreators.getAttributes())
          }
    }
}

DropDownList.propTypes = {
    availableAttributes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    activeFilters: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }
export default connect(mapStatesToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(DropDownList)
```

```

My solution for case one for the second error was to just place the ajax function call into in object that contains the "type" property. Like such

```js
return (

  {
    type: "Something",


    $.ajax('/getFilteredAttributes/', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(response => {
      dispatch(addAttribute("make", 32));
    }).fail((xhr, status, error) => {
      console.log("failed");
    })

  })
```

The ajax call is made, but dispatch still isn't available, I am lost and looking for the best solution? Maybe I am overthinking something or missed a minor detail. I have tried other solutions but none has worked for me.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to know exactly what's going on, but I definitely wouldn't recommend ignoring / hacking round an error you're getting using a common feature of a popular library. It's important to get your implementation right for simplicity moving forward.

It looks to me like the way you are using thunk is a little odd.
The function that is **returned** by the action you dispatch has dispatch and getState as arguments:

In your case your thunk action might look like this

**In your actions.js:**

```
export function getAttributes2(){
  return function(dispatch, getState){
    // you could dispatch a fetching action here before requesting!
    return $.ajax('/getFilteredAttributes/', {type: 'GET', dataType: 'json'})
      .done(response => dispatch(saveTheResponseAction(response)))
      .fail((xhr, status, error) => console.log("failed"))
}
```

**Mapping that thunk function to your props:**

```
import {getAttributes2} from '../../../redux/actions/actions';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getAttributes2: () => dispatch(getAttributes2()),
  }
}
```

This way you can dispatch an action from the .done part of your api call with the result in it, you can respond to errors, you can even dispatch an action before returning your api call to let redux know you've requested but not yet received the data, allowing you to do all kinds of loading states.

I hope this helps, let me know :)

Comment: Nope, error currently is: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Comment: Ok, so there must be some problem in the way you have the middleware set up I guess. Can you set up a simple CRA project and check you can get thunk up and running in a very simple environment first.

Comment: Yeah, the setup of the actual middleware is in mainstore.js. I just followed the tutorials, I have no idea why I am not able to run dispatch function or if thunk is running properly.